# Why can't XML validation find my XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, include

I'm making schema files for a large XML file where its XSD file is using a lot of other schema files that it is including from other minor schema files. Everytime I'm trying to validate it comes up and says that it can't find the schema information for the element.

I have tried to add `targetNamespaces` or using `import`, but it keeps coming up with the errors. The Config XSD file includes all the other smaller schema files without any problems.

```
<Config xmlns="C:\Users\xs\Desktop\Config.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="C:\Users\xs\Desktop\Config.xsd">
  <test>
    <test2>
      <TestDatabase Key="no">
        <Class>blablabla</Class>
      </TestDatabase>
      <TestTimetable Key="no">
        <Class>blablabla</Class>
        <Report>
          <Component>1</Component>
          <Connection>1</Connection>
        </Report>
        <Connect>
          <Delay>15</Delay>
          <Period>30</Period>
        </Connect>
        <Abc>
          <Factory>jk</Factory>
          <Url>www.jk.com</Url>
          <Topic>a</Topic>
          <Queue>1</Queue>
          <User>p1</User>
          <Password>xxx</Password>
        </Abc>
      </TestTimetable>
    </test2>
  </test>
</Config>
```

The schema file for the Config XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="file:///C:\Users\xs\Desktop\TestDatabase.xsd" />
  <xs:include schemaLocation="file:///C:\Users\xs\Desktop\TestTimetable.xsd" />
  <xs:element name="Config">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Test">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Test2">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="TestDatabase" type="TestDatabaseType" />
                    <xs:element name="TestTimetable" type="TestTimetableType" /> 
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And `TestTimetableType` have its own includes from schemas like the `Report` and `Connect`.

Comment: It might help if you show the entire Config.xsd file (you've left out the xs:schema element and its attributes) and if you share the specific error messages.  It may be the issue is related to namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to do this without namespaces...

**(1) Delete this line in your XML file:**

```
    xmlns="C:\Users\xs\Desktop\Config.xsd"
```

**(2) change this line in your XML file:**

```
    xsi:schemaLocation="C:\Users\xs\Desktop\Config.xsd">
```

**to this:**

```
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///C:\Users\xs\Desktop\Config.xsd">
```

**Explanation:**

- The `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute is for when you have a namespace.  It takes
  namespace-URI ***pairs***; use `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` to specify an XSD without a namespace.
- Use `file:///` when you wish to specify the full path to a local XSD.

Note also that XML is case sensitive, so `test` is not the same as `Test` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the clarification on schemaLocation, the error was in typos in the include of the other schemas far down the chain.